# Import Strings.rexs to excel file from Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio MACOSX

Tags: excel, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio, resx

Hi I used macosx Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

I want to convert long String.resx to excel file with two column key and value for client translation purposes. Is there any tool or any other way to simplify rather to copy and paste all keys and value one by one of Strings.resx to excel file.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager

Comment: thanks. Is it available for mac?